# Ant build can't find .txt files in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am working on a Java project in Eclipse and am currently writing unit tests for it.

To get a nice, interactive summary of the test results I generate a build.xml file by doing

File >> Export >> Ant Buildfiles >> "Checking my project" and pressing Finish

I then configure the build file using the Edit Configuration view in Eclipse and choose the tests (suites) I want to run and finish with junitreport.

This works perfectly for except the small fact that the configuration .txt files I have can not be found when running via Ant. If I run the src files of the tests everything works as expected.

I read a file to an InputStream like this

```
//CONFIG = "CONFIG/config.txt"
public static InputStream getConfigInputStream() throws IOException{
    File file = new File(CONFIG);
    return new FileInputStream(file);
}
```

Here is an example output from the console:

```
NameValidationTest:
   [junit] Running se.st.dsg.pc.test.junit_test.tests.unit_tests.NameValidationTest
   [junit] Tests run: 4, Failures: 2, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,123 sec
   [junit] Error: 
   [junit] java.io.FileNotFoundException: CONFIG\config.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
   [junit]  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
   [junit]  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
   [junit]  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
   [junit]  at se.st.dsg.input_stream_source.InputStreamSource.getConfigInputStream(InputStreamSource.java:26)
   [junit]  at se.st.dsg.core.syst_params.SystParamsParser.parseConfig(SystParamsParser.java:40)
   [junit]  at se.st.dsg.pc.test.junit_test.tests.unit_tests.NameValidationTest.setup(NameValidationTest.java:20)
   [junit]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   [junit]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   [junit]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   [junit]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   [junit]  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
   [junit]  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
   [junit]  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
   [junit]  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
   [junit]  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
   [junit]  at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:38)
   [junit]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:535)
   [junit]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1182)
   [junit]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:1033)
   [junit] Test se.st.dsg.pc.test.junit_test.tests.unit_tests.NameValidationTest FAILED
```

I would like to stress that this error does NOT happen when compiling and running normally in Eclipse, and that the tests that don't read a .txt file works as expected when using Ant. Do I have to tell Ant where the files are located, or is there some other way of solving this problem?

Comment: Don't use backslashes.  Also your current working directory is most likely not what  you expect it to be.

Comment: You might want to print out file.getAbsolutePath() after creation.  It helps immensely.

Comment: Thanks Thorbjørn, I see now with your simple tip that the path is different when running Ant, it becomes the path to the Eclipse .exe folder, followed by the CONFIG/config.txt. How do I get Ant to understand where my project is actually located?

Comment: Use an ant property pointing to a file in your project, and use that to compute your path.  You may want to make your configuration directory settable from the command line.